# Ejecutar Archivo .BAT como administrador sin dar click derecho, incluir credenciales en codigo

Tags: .bat

quiero crear un BAT que agregue un grupo a a los administradores, pero no quiero darle click derecho y abrir como administrador, si no que en la linea del codigo ponga yo las credenciales (anexo imagen para la guia)  y este las tome e ahi para ejecutar la accion anexo ejemplo de los poco que tengo:

```
@echo off
color 40
echo                ==================================
echo                              = =
echo                   = agregar a sistemas_local  =
echo                              = =
echo                ==================================
echo.
echo.
cls
:start
start net localgroup administrators "na\sistemas_local" /add
pause presiona cualquier boton para salir
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

miré varias formas de hacer lo que quieres y la única forma que encontré aunque no me gusta mucho es utilizando el comando `runas`. Yo el problema que le veo y por el cual no me gusta es que abre otra consola de cmd con los permisos de admin en vez de utilizar el cmd ya existente. Yo supongo es que en Windows no se puede cambiar de sesión en el cmd como si fuera Linux utilizando `sudo`.
Y el comando `runas` ejecuta un .exe con los permisos del usuario que le especifiques.

```
@echo off
color 40
echo                ==================================
echo                              = =
echo                   = agregar a sistemas_local  =
echo                              = =
echo                ==================================
echo.
echo.
cls
:start
runas /noprofile /env /user:<UsusarioConPermisos> "net localgroup administrators "na\sistemas_local" /add"
pause presiona cualquier boton para salir
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma que me parece conveniente es: crear un acceso directo del .bat, luego al acceso directo le damos click derecho, propiedades, luego en opciones avanzadas y marcamos la casilla ejecutar como administrador.

Fuente: https://www.softzone.es/windows/como-se-hace/ejecutar-archivo-bat-administrador/

Answer (score 0):

La manera en que lo realice fue creando un acceso directo del archivo .bat
A este acceso directo en propiedades - Acceso directo, marcas la opcion de ejecutar como administrador.
En teoria te deberia dejar.

[image: Imagen Ejemplo]

Comment: Hola Jhon, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, es importante antes de responder, leer detenidamente la pregunta y los comentarios (si los hubiese), tu respuesta propone hacer lo que el OP, quiere evitar, te sugiero que la elimines a fin de evitar votos negativos.